# Migrated from AMD to Intel and grub doesn't boot Linux

Tags: grub, intel, amd

I have Linux Mint 21.2 installed on an NVMe M.2 SSD. I migrated from a Ryzen 5 3600X to an Intel Core i9-14900K CPU and motherboard, and now grub welcomes me with the following screen:

```
GNU GRUB  version 2.04

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
lists possible device or file completion. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
device or file completions.

grub>
```

I figured that I can boot up my system with the following commands:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
linux /vmlinuz-5.15.0-88-generic root=/dev/mapper/vg-mint ro
initrd /initrd.img-5.15.0-88-generic
boot
```

I've tried running `update-grub` and various commands to no avail. Any help would be appreciated to make grub automatically boot my system.

Comment: what are the *and various commands*? was one of them `update-initramfs`

Comment: You now have a very new system, so need the newest available operating system to have latest kernel & drivers. You also show grub 2.04 and 2.06 is now more common with current versions. You also show MBR(msdos) partitions. Systems since 2012 are UEFI and should use gpt partitions. Note conversion from MBR to gpt will normally totally erase drive, so good backups required.

Comment: Looks like you had MBR/BIOS partitioning/booting and Raptor Lake is UEFI only. You need to fix GRUB conf files.

Comment: @JaromandaX I've just tried `update-initramfs -c -k all`, and it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You need to update you GRUB config files or even recreate them. Unfortunately I use Fedora's GRUB, so I cannot tell you how it's done in your distro. Maybe you need to install grub-pc-efi package or something.

Comment: @oldfred Linux Mint 21.2 is the newest version of the distribution. I've installed the newest available kernel, which is 6.2.0-39, but it didn't make a difference. Thinking about it, it probably shouldn't because grub isn't able to load the kernel automatically to begin with.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've installed `grub-efi-amd64-bin`, `grub-efi-ia32-bin`, then updated initramfs, and the issue persists.

Comment: I'll convert my partitions to GPT, and I'll report back on my findings.

Comment: Most conversions to gpt totally erase entire hard drive, be sure to have good backups. You can use this, but its better for data only drives. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html  man fdisk # disk labels section:
"GPT is always a better choice than MBR, especially on modern hardware with a UEFI boot loader."

Comment: *Most conversions to gpt totally erase entire hard drive, be sure to have good backups* gdisk does that seamlessly without losing anything.